# Symbolizing lines based average value of point (start, middle, end) in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, symbology

There are three points in each line of road network, each point has weight and I want to give the average weight of these three points to corresponding line and symbolized all the lines accordingly. Any idea how to do it?! To remind you both points and lines are two different shape files.
Point values are centrality measures!

[image: three points can be seen here]

Comment: It looks to me like some points are at the start-/end point of two different lines. is this the case?

Comment: Yes it is, but I am still lost how to transfer the average weight of three nodes to the corresponding link. Doesn't matter if one point is the start of one line and the end of another one.

Comment: Is there a field (and matching value) common to the points and lines? Also do the start and end points contain duplicates (i.e. are there two points coincident where two lines meet)?

Comment: All mid points FIDs are matched with lines, which is a good thing. Whereas, the start and end points contain duplicates, means start point of one line is the end point of the previous line.